# Support Mac editing keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: feature-request, keyboard-shortcuts

The keyboard shortcuts that Stack Overflow seems to be Windows native (I'm not sure, as I haven't used Windows for 10 years). GitHub provides shortcuts for editing that reflect the native platform conventions, e.g. Command+K creates a link. They also bind to Command instead of Control on Mac.

It would be great if Stack Overflow keyboard shortcuts followed platform conventions.

Comment: The hovertext also says "Ctrl+[key]" instead of "Cmd+[key]" even though both work unless the shortcut is also an OSX shortcut (for example both Ctrl+K and Cmd+K start a code block but Cmd+L doesn't insert a link, it jumps to the address bar).

Comment: @PeterG That's gonna be fun if someone tries out Cmd-K to see if it's Cmd on Mac instead of Ctrl, and then goes ahead to use Cmd-Q...

Comment: Cmd+K needs to work on chat.stackoverflow aswell.

Comment: @Siguza yes, that was indeed funny... And actually the first I tested after cmd-k lol

Comment: command+k is already used for the focused search in vivaldi on macs.